# Why would you use `const`?

Tags: julia

I'm looking at a code base and I see the use of the keyboard `const`, e.g.

```
const L1 = 1.0
```

What's the meaning of `const` and whats more important, why would you use it? that is, why wouldn't just define a variable in the normal way?

Comment: Also note that rebinding a variable declared as `const` to an other object of the same type in Julia <= 1.8 will result in a warning, not an error (that you will have if instead you rebind the variable to an object of a different type)

Answer (score 3):

TLDR:

Julia uses lexical scoping, and closures can hurt performance. Using `const` allows Julia to know the type of the value in a global variable at function compile time, and hence Julia can generate fast machine code for it. At the time of writing, `const` can only be used in the global scope. `const` for global variables also helps managing state and keeping your program simpler to understand.

---

From the [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/), you'll see this:

> a function's scope does not inherit from its caller's scope, but from the scope in which the function was defined.

What that means is that if you have a `test.jl` with the following Julia code as an example:

```
L1 = 1.0

function foo()
  return L1 + 1
end
```

you can run it without any errors, e.g.:

```
julia> include("test.jl")
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo()
2.0
```

The function `foo()` is able to access a variable defined in the scope where `foo` itself was defined.

Lexical scoping in Julia means that the scope allows nesting:

```
L1 = 1.0

function bar()
  L2 = 2.0

  function foo()
    L1 + L2
  end

  foo()
end
```

```
julia> include("test.jl")
bar (generic function with 1 method)

julia> bar()
3.0
```

It's important to realize that there's three different scopes here, the global scope where the `L1` variable is defined, the function scope where `L2`  is defined and the inner function scope where both `L1` and `L2` closures are held.

Lexical scoping in Julia only lets you access back up until the module scope:

```
L1 = 1.0

module Foo

  function foo()
    L1 + 1.0
  end

end
```

```
julia> include("test.jl")
Main.Foo

julia> Foo.foo()
ERROR: UndefVarError: L1 not defined
Stacktrace:
  ...
```

What is important to understand is that when the function is called that contains a variable defined outside of its own scope, it has to "lookup" the value of a variable outside of itself *at runtime*, and the runtime value of this variable is what is used in the function. This is typically referred to as a function "closing over" a variable, or the variable is typically referred to as a closure in the context of the function.

Because the value is referred to at runtime, you can have other functions modify the variable. For example, if you have the following code:

```
L1 = 1.0

function foo()
  L1 + 1.0
end

function bar()
  global L1
  L1 += 1.0
end

function baz()
  global L1
  L1 = "Hello world"
end
```

```
julia> include("test.jl")
bar (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo()
2.0

julia> bar()
2.0

julia> bar()
3.0

julia> bar()
4.0

julia> foo()
5.0

julia> baz()
"Hello world"

julia> foo()
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching +(::String, ::Float64)
Closest candidates are:
  +(::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any...) at operators.jl:591
  +(::T, ::T) where T<:Union{Float16, Float32, Float64} at float.jl:383
  +(::Base.TwicePrecision, ::Number) at twiceprecision.jl:290
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] foo()
```

One of the reasons global variables are bad is that it can make managing state unwieldy. If `bar()`, `baz()` and a dozen other similar functions defined in different files (remember all sibling `include("filename.jl")` are part of the same scope) can modify the value of `L1`, it can be quite difficult to reason about the code when you are trying to understand what `foo()` is doing just by looking at the local context of `foo()`.

This by itself makes it worth using the `const` keyword on all global variables.

However, in Julia, we have another concern to address too. As you may be aware, Julia generates machine code "on the fly" before running your code. We can actually take a peek at what the code is using `@code_llvm`.

```
julia> @code_llvm foo()
;  @ C:\gitrepos\test.jl:3 within `foo`
; Function Attrs: uwtable
define nonnull {}* @julia_foo_1218() #0 {
top:
  %0 = alloca [2 x {}*], align 8
  %gcframe2 = alloca [3 x {}*], align 16
  %gcframe2.sub = getelementptr inbounds [3 x {}*], [3 x {}*]* %gcframe2, i64 0, i64 0
  %.sub = getelementptr inbounds [2 x {}*], [2 x {}*]* %0, i64 0, i64 0
  %1 = bitcast [3 x {}*]* %gcframe2 to i8*
  call void @llvm.memset.p0i8.i32(i8* noundef nonnull align 16 dereferenceable(24) %1, i8 0, i32 24, i1 false)
  %2 = call {}*** inttoptr (i64 140733076536976 to {}*** ()*)() #3
  %3 = bitcast [3 x {}*]* %gcframe2 to i64*
  store i64 4, i64* %3, align 16
  %4 = getelementptr inbounds [3 x {}*], [3 x {}*]* %gcframe2, i64 0, i64 1
  %5 = bitcast {}** %4 to {}***
  %6 = load {}**, {}*** %2, align 8
  store {}** %6, {}*** %5, align 8
  %7 = bitcast {}*** %2 to {}***
  store {}** %gcframe2.sub, {}*** %7, align 8
  %8 = load atomic {}*, {}** inttoptr (i64 1976714741720 to {}**) unordered, align 8
  %9 = getelementptr inbounds [3 x {}*], [3 x {}*]* %gcframe2, i64 0, i64 2
  store {}* %8, {}** %9, align 16
  store {}* %8, {}** %.sub, align 8
  %10 = getelementptr inbounds [2 x {}*], [2 x {}*]* %0, i64 0, i64 1
  store {}* inttoptr (i64 140732435224032 to {}*), {}** %10, align 8
  %11 = call nonnull {}* @ijl_apply_generic({}* inttoptr (i64 140732359508544 to {}*), {}** nonnull %.sub, i32 2)
  %12 = load {}*, {}** %4, align 8
  %13 = bitcast {}*** %2 to {}**
  store {}* %12, {}** %13, align 8
  ret {}* %11
}
```

There's a lot of code here, but the short version of this is that Julia has to use pointer based arithmetic to access the value in the closure. This can be slow for a machine to run.

On the other hand, let's say you decide to use `const`:

```
const L1 = 1.0

function foo()
  L1 + 1.0
end
```

```
julia> include("test.jl")
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo()
2.0

julia> @code_llvm foo()
;  @ C:\gitrepos\test.jl:3 within `foo`
; Function Attrs: uwtable
define double @julia_foo_857() #0 {
top:
  ret double 2.000000e+00
}
```

The code generated for `@code_llvm foo()` is just one line - `return 2.0`.

Julia is able to track that it is a `const` value that cannot change, and because the value cannot change that means that the type of the value also cannot change. And hence Julia is able to generate code that doesn't need to create a closure. This allows Julia (and LLVM) to make a bunch of optimiziations. In this case, Julia even does the math at compile time and just returns the value `2.0`.

If you wanted to compare the actual performance, you can see it using BenchmarkTools:

```
L1 = 1.0

function foo1()
  L1 + 1.0
end

const L2 = 1.0

function foo2()
  L2 + 1.0
end
```

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools;

julia> include("test.jl");

julia> @benchmark foo1()
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 998 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  18.337 ns … 653.908 ns  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 95.94%
 Time  (median):     19.439 ns               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   20.916 ns ±  11.195 ns  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.89% ±  1.66%

  ▁▃▁█▇▄▂▁  ▁▃▂▂▂▄▆▅▃▁     ▁                                   ▂
  ████████▇███████████▇█▇███▇█▆██▇▆▅▆▆▆▄▅▆▄▅▆▆▆▆▅▅▄▃▃▁▃▃▄▅▅▄▅▅ █
  18.3 ns       Histogram: log(frequency) by time      33.7 ns <

 Memory estimate: 16 bytes, allocs estimate: 1.

julia> @benchmark foo2()
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 1000 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  0.900 ns … 9.300 ns  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     0.900 ns             ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   0.935 ns ± 0.103 ns  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

  █          
  █▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁█▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▂ ▂
  0.9 ns         Histogram: frequency by time        1.1 ns <

 Memory estimate: 0 bytes, allocs estimate: 0.
```

You can see that `foo2()` run an order of magnitude faster.

The only downside of using `const` is that if you want to make a change to the value, you can't do it in the same session. You'll have to restart the Julia session. If you are using `Revise`, this can make prototyping a little annoying.

Also, as of Julia 1.8.5, you can only use `const` in the global scope, i.e. you cannot use `const L1 = 1.0` instead a function. If you want to use a closure inside an inner function, you can use type hinting to let the Julia compiler know what the type of the closure should be.

FWIW, I try to avoid the use of global variables as much as possible. If I need to use data across functions, I create a `struct` that holds all the values I want to use in various functions and just pass that `struct` around.

If I need to use global variables, they are always with a `const` keyword before them. I might leave off the `const` keyword during prototyping, but I always add them in as soon as possible.

Sometimes, I like to use global variables to keep track of the things that would use useful to calculate at module load time, e.g. the path to the current folder, or "magic numbers" that will be used in a number of different functions that I might want to tweak later. These are typically values that are always fast to calculate, require little to no allocations, etc.

If I absolutely need to keep track of a global state, I do that using a `Ref` with a `const` keyword. Here's an example:

```
const L1 = Ref(1.0)

function foo()
  L1[] + 1.0
end

function bar()
  L1[] += 1
end
```

```
julia> include("test.jl")
bar (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo()
2.0

julia> bar()
2.0

julia> bar()
3.0

julia> bar()
4.0

julia> foo()
5.0

julia> @code_llvm foo()
;  @ C:\gitrepos\test.jl:3 within `foo`
; Function Attrs: uwtable
define double @julia_foo_849() #0 {
top:
;  @ C:\gitrepos\test.jl:4 within `foo`
; ┌ @ refvalue.jl:56 within `getindex`
; │┌ @ Base.jl:38 within `getproperty`
    %0 = load double, double* inttoptr (i64 1685521213616 to double*), align 16
; └└
; ┌ @ float.jl:383 within `+`
   %1 = fadd double %0, 1.000000e+00
; └
  ret double %1
}

julia> @benchmark foo()
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 1000 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  1.600 ns … 6.300 ns  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     1.600 ns             ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   1.673 ns ± 0.191 ns  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

  █    
  █▁▁▁▁▆▁▁▁▁▁▅▁▁▁▁▁▂▁▁▁▁▂▁▁▁▁▁▂▁▁▁▁▁▂▁▁▁▁▂▁▁▁▁▁▂▁▁▁▁▁▂▁▁▁▁▂ ▂
  1.6 ns         Histogram: frequency by time        2.6 ns <

 Memory estimate: 0 bytes, allocs estimate: 0.
```

Hope that helps!

References:

- https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/
- https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/
- https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/c/#Core.Ref

Comment: Summarizing this answer would be helpful.

Comment: I added a TLDR!

Answer (score 1):

`const` means that the variable can't change. This is useful because annotating a variable with `const` allows the compiler to determine the type of the variable (as mentioned in the [Performance tips)](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/).

As of 1.8 you can get most of the performance improvement by annotating the type.

```
L1::Float64 = 1.0
```

Note that this only applies to global variables. For variables inside functions, the compiler can already figure out variable types via type inference.